# iphone sdk how to add uitableview cell image dynamically?

Tags: iphone, uiimageview

I am new to this iPhone development. Am developing a catalogue application. In that i need to give all product details with product images as tableview cell image dynamically since my images are coming from web service. I did this,

```
NSString* imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[stories objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"product_thumb_image"]];
cell.imageView.image.size.width==20;
cell.imageView.image.size.height==20;
cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];
NSLog(@"imagename:%@",[[stories objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"product_thumb_image"]);
```

Am getting all the images in my console window and i checked that using nslog. But am not getting the images with simulator.What am doing wrong in this? Can anyone of you help me out?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UIImage imageNamed:` takes an NSString so if you want to use a formatted string like that use `NSString`'s stringWithFormat

try:

```
cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",currentLink]];
```

As you are new to iPhone development I'll just expand that out to make it clearer (Ignore this if you already got what was happening there)

```
NSString* imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",currentLink];
cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];
```

Answer (score 0):

Do as follows:

```
NSString *imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",currentLink];
cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];
```

Answer (score 0):

Apple documentation contains an example of putting downloaded images into table cells.  It's called LazyTableImages and would probably help with what you're trying to do.